# Simple dev stack for React and JSX with ES5

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am starting out with React and I'd like to write my app in ES5. I have created an html with `script` tags for `react.min.js`, `react-dom.min.js` and my own `app.js` file. Now what do I need to do in order to be able to write JSX in my JavaScript file?

1. Would the preprocessing (JSX into JS) typically be done on the server? Or is there a way to do it on the client?
2. I would like to keep my development stack simple. Do I have to look into webpack or is there a simpler way to handle JSX (e.g. by npm script or through express)?
3. Everyone seems to be using babel. Can I do without it if I write plain old ES5?

P.S: I will use NodeJS and Express on the server side to deliver the app.

Comment: I wonder: What is your reason for not using ES6?

Comment: I have existing code that I would like to re-use. It's written in CoffeeScript and compiles into ES5.

Comment: I think official docs cover this question a bit here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html and https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-jsx.html

Comment: @yuyokk The link describes how to write react components in ES5, however, my question is about how to compile JSX into JS.

Comment: I see, you can use `React.createElement()` instead of JSX.

Comment: Why should I not use JSX?

Comment: I think there are no reasons to not use JSX. It's pretty awesome. But you will need to run some tool to translate JSX into `React.createElement`. Docs suggest using `babel`.

Comment: Normally ,the preprocessing is on server side ,you need some building tool and the default one in React community is webpack ,follow this https://survivejs.com/webpack/introduction/
If you really want ,there is a way to trans-compile jsx on client side, but it is mainly for testing purpose .Basically you should specify `<script type='babel'>` and load `babel` library .I can not even find a tutorial for you online ,maybe no one use it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to answer as detail as possible your questions:

1. You could transpile JSX on server with Browserify and save some time, React will add a flag to all their components to mark the components as rendered in Server, but what most of the people is doing now is using webpack to transpile all the code before to run your application. You could do it on the client too, but I would suggest you to compile before to run your application.
2. You could use browserify with npm to transpile your code together with babel before to run you
3. Yes you can as soon as your explorer and your client's explorer support ES5, if not you will get an error and nothing will work, that's why everyone is using babel to support ES5 or ES6 in mostly all the browsers.

Hope this help you!